# Hide sources (folders) in the browser devtool

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am looking for a way to hide some folders or files, for example in the chrome inspect tool (F12) under the sources tab.

I am developing a web application with angularjs and i want to hide the app folder that contain some js files with sensible data.

Comment: From whom do you want do hide it?

Comment: Your sensible data must not be exposed in a public html folder. Call it from a non sensible file.

Comment: hi fracz, thank you for your answer. kann you explain what you mean?